# Python 3.11.5 - Error Enabling jupyter_nbextensions_configurator: ModuleNotFoundError for notebook.base

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-3.11

I'm encountering an issue when trying to enable `jupyter_nbextensions_configurator` on my Jupyter setup. I get the following error message:

```
jupyter_nbextensions_configurator | error adding extension (enabled: True): The module 'jupyter_nbextensions_configurator' could not be found (No module named 'notebook.base'). Are you sure the extension is installed?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/extension/manager.py", line 319, in add_extension
    extpkg = ExtensionPackage(name=extension_name, enabled=enabled)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/extension/manager.py", line 183, in __init__
    self._load_metadata()
  File "[...]/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/extension/manager.py", line 198, in _load_metadata
    raise ExtensionModuleNotFound(msg) from None
jupyter_server.extension.utils.ExtensionModuleNotFound: The module 'jupyter_nbextensions_configurator' could not be found (No module named 'notebook.base'). Are you sure the extension is installed?
```

When I try activating `nbextensions_configurator` using the command line, I get:

```
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/bin/jupyter-nbextensions_configurator", line 5, in <module>
    from jupyter_nbextensions_configurator.application import main
  File "[...]/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from notebook.base.handlers import APIHandler, IPythonHandler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.base'
```

##### My package versions are as follows:

- Python 3.11.5
- pip 23.2.1
- notebook 7.0.3
- jupyter 1.0.0
- jupyter_client 8.3.1
- jupyter_console 6.6.3
- jupyter-contrib-core 0.4.2
- jupyter-contrib-nbextensions 0.7.0
- jupyter_core 5.3.1
- jupyter-events 0.7.0
- jupyter-highlight-selected-word 0.2.0
- jupyter-lsp 2.2.0
- jupyter-nbextensions-configurator 0.6.3
- jupyter_server 2.7.2
- jupyter_server_terminals 0.4.4
- jupyterlab 4.0.5
- jupyterlab-pygments 0.2.2
- jupyterlab_server 2.24.0
- jupyterlab-widgets 3.0.8

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Any guidance on how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.